# Where to group UIViews into a custom UIView?

Tags: swift, uiview

I am trying to clean up my `viewController` and make it lighter.

I am programming the UI in code and have a group of elements which I wanted to extract into a custom `UIView`. I want to use it kind of like "container view".  I would then just add this single `UIView` to my `view controller` which declutters my `viewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` function significantly.

I know I can't/shouldn't use `drawRect()`. Is it better to add subviews to a custom `init()` function or to add the subviews to `layoutSubviews()`? Or is there a different place that is meant for adding subviews and their constraints to a custom `UIView`? Or should I actually be using `UIContainerView`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends if you are using `NSLayoutConstraint`s or frame based math. i recommend using `NSLayoutConstraint`s because of its simplicity once setup. i also find creating smooth rotations much easier via auto layout.

if you are using `NSLayoutConstraint`s you should initialize, add and layout subviews inside init().

if you are doing frame based math you should initialize and add your subviews inside init() (with empty frames) and then lay them out in layoutSubviews(). this makes it so rotation is handled for you.

for either case i recommend making each of the subviews a lazy loader ivar. each lazy loader should perform all setup customization (background color, font, text color, etc) for its associated view. this will allow your init() method to be very light.

**Contrived Example:**

```
import UIKit

class AvatarView: UIView {

    init(username: String, rank: String) {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)

        usernameLabel.text = username
        rankLabel.text = rank

        self.addSubview(iconView)
        self.addSubview(usernameLabel)
        self.addSubview(rankLabel)

        _layoutViews()
    }

    private func _layoutViews() {
        let views = ["iconView":iconView, "usernameLabel":usernameLabel, "rankLabel":rankLabel]
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[iconView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[usernameLabel]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-6-[rankLabel]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[iconView]-6-[usernameLabel(==20)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-6-[rankLabel]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    }

    private lazy var usernameLabel: UILabel = {
        let view = UILabel()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
        view.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        view.textAlignment = .Center
        return view
    }()

    private lazy var rankLabel: UILabel = {
        let view = UILabel()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(40)
        view.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        return view
    }()

    lazy var iconView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("unused")
    }
}
```